# How to stay at the same page after page reload in Angular

Tags: angular, single-page-application, page-refresh

Few days ago I have started learning Angular and tried to do a simple SPA. I have added 2 components and routing for them:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'main', component: MainPageComponent}, //default page
  {path: 'registration-form', component: RegistrationPageComponent}, //"another" page
  {path: 'login-form', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

So I have default routing to main page and the button on it, which navigates to another page (component):

```
<button style="border-color: transparent;"  type="button"
        class="item7 btn btn-secondary btn-pill" [routerLink]="['/registration-form']">
   <i class="fa fa-sign-in mr-2"></i>
   {{logButtonTitle}}
</button>
```

When I click on this button, it successfully navigates me to another page (component), but if I press F5 on the other page (browser page reload) my application forgets my second page and loads the default one.
So, I don't know how to stay on another page after page reloading and if can I do it at all.

P.s. - I tried to find any information about it, but all solutions that I found didn't help me.

Thanks!

Update:
The code in app.components.ts

Here I load default page always when application starts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/main']);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can store the current path on local storage so you can load it when the app is first loaded.

Comment: Can you create a sample stackblitz of the your code so I can understand your issue in better way. Or may be you can add code of app.component.ts so I can understand your problem.Thanks

Comment: @julianobrasil This is the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: No... you can also store the current URL path to a database... this way the user can reopen the app on the last visited route anywhere heshe opens the app.

Comment: Remove the navigate to main in the app component. Set up a default route redirect as shown here: https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always redirected to your `main` route because you are specifying in your root component to navigate to the `main` route.

Everytime the app is reloaded its routing state is lost. So you should remove that from your root component. I don't understand why you're doing like that.

If you want the `main` route to be used by default, in your routing module add this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // first line redirects to '/main' instead of '/'
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main',
  {path: 'main', component: MainPageComponent}, //default page
  {path: 'registration-form', component: RegistrationPageComponent}, //"another" page
  {path: 'login-form', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

Comment: ionut-t, sorry for my stupid mistakes with router, i just tried to set default page, but i didn't know another way to do it, thank you very much for you help, now it works!

Comment: @iCnoK I'm glad that I could help you. you don't have to be sorry. we all made mistakes, especially when starting to work with new technology. Angular can be hard to grasp when you're first starting with it and usually, it is a love-hate relationship. Happy coding!